# Android Google places API REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-mapview, android-maps

Hello I am using GOOGLE maps API for android, and using my API key I am able to draw map.

Also added zoom in zoom out function. But when I try to fetch data from google API it gives me REQUEST_DENIED error message.

Here is my query string

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=43.666,93.166&radius=5000&sensor=false&types=establishment&name=hotel&key={myKey}
```

I have tried many [links to generate key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey)

Also tried [this](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) link.

Help needed stuck in this problem for the last two days.

Comment: what data are you trying to fetch? Because if you can render the MapView correctly i don't think the problem is with the API key. Try to use the webservices :http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="
                        + URL.encode(addressField.getText()) + "&sensor=false

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=43.666,93.166&radius=5000&sensor=false&types=establishment&name=hotel&key={key}

Comment: here is the link in my previous comment.....i don't know whats the problem. yes i can see/draw map clearly.

Comment: The Places API key is not the same as Maps API key .. Enable Places API on your console page

Answer (score 1):

If your keyApi is a android key won't work because you need a browser api (leave in black for all access allowed). From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224080/request-denied-with-google-places-api-browser-key-or-app-key)

"Accessing Google places API involves a http/https request from the browser. The application key you created wouldn't work for the Google places as it needs a browser key. You need to create a new browser key on the Google API console clicking the "Create new Browser Key"

Also leave the Accept requests from these HTTP referers (web sites): blank so that it allows access to all referrers and include the key generated in your query URL."