# REQUEST_DENIED with Google Places API browser key or app key?

Tags: android, api, key

I'm writing an application in Android that needs the Google Places API.
I have made a key through the Google console, for both my browser and my specific application. The application key already works with Google Maps.
To do a request to the Google Places API, though, it seems I have to use the browser key for it to work. It won't work with the application key, because that results in a REQUEST_DENIED.

Somebody knows how this is possible? Or is this normal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Accessing Google places API  involves a http/https request from the browser. The application key you created wouldn't work for the Google places as it needs a browser key. You need to create a new browser key on the Google API console clicking the "Create new Browser Key"

Also leave the **Accept requests from these HTTP referers (web sites):** blank so that it allows access to all referrers and include the key generated in your query URL.

Comment: save my day too thanks friends, i just was confused at one point and for those who was wondering as i did. Generate a browser key using your ip address,  and use that key for the request not the application key. It will work for sure thanks for asking question and answering save my day :)

Comment: Great! This matter was a puzzle for me until today :)

Comment: How safe is it to not put in a HTTP referrer though?