# Google Map API For Near By Place By Latitude and Longitude

Tags: android, json, api, google-maps

I have an Api key, Api console and Sh1, and using EclipseIDE ANDROID -> preference, I
added all data in Api as below:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=48.859294,2.347589&radius=5000&types=food|cafe&sensor=false&keyword=vegetarian&key=AIzaSyCRQ2aFtbU2sOgO6fMvuM2edHPaWRDxbRg`

But I get this error message:

```
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your key is not yet authorized. You probably have to get it approved/verified by Google - did you pay for it?

Comment: check validity of api key once.& package name which you have mentioned in api key

Comment: Generate new Api Key with permission added into it or edit your previous key by adding a service Places Api into it

Answer (score 1):

I request you to Use following API

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.859294,2.347589&radius=500&types=school&sensor=false&key=my-key`

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same issue you were experiencing, I used the same api as you however what I found was that if you generate a new API key for android it does not work, but if you generate a new Server key and use that it works perfectly. I found some assistance on the following post [REQUEST_DENIED with Google Places API browser key or app key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224080/request-denied-with-google-places-api-browser-key-or-app-key)