# Google Places API Key for Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-play-services, google-places-api

I have created an `API Key` (for Android apps) for my Android Application. It was required by google maps API. But now the same key won't work for Google Places API.

I also tried hitting the browser with the following URL:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=my_key

I get:

```
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

When I googled for an answer, I found this:

https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

> What type of API key?
>
> You'll need your own browser or server API key for the Google Places API before you can begin using the Place Autcomplete service. Note that an Android API key will not work for the Place Autocomplete service.

This got me confused as I do not have any URL for a web app, nor any server IP. Therefore I am confused on how to get either a `Browser key` or a `Server key`

Could anyone please help me in figuring out what sort of key is needed here? Also if I have to create a `Browser key` or a `Server key`, how can I do so?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224080/request-denied-with-google-places-api-browser-key-or-app-key

Comment: u must have already generated an android api key , so again click on "Create Key" , you will get options , server key , browser key , android key , ios key 
First click on server key , leave the place blank and click on create , your server key will be generated , save it.

Answer (score 5):

For working with places api generate browser key because for that android key does not work.
Had same issue but this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the following places api

-Google Places API Web Service

And you are required to use server key for fetching the data of places.

To get a server key follow the below steps: APIs & Auth -> Credentials -> create new key -> Server key

Browser key will not work.

I had the same issue and I resolved it by doing the same.

Here you can have a look to build your Url

```
 StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" + type);
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + SERVER_KEY);
```

Comment: This question was asked over a year ago;  While it may be a correct answer now, it is unlikely that the original poster is still encountering this issue.

Comment: I posted this answer for the ones who are facing the problem or will have the same problem, as after looking on SO when i did not find the cause and resolved it later, i thought it might be helpful for someone else also.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you were aware of the age of the question;  Posting knowledge for others to reference is always a great thing as long as it's presented as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate Google Place Api in android project and you need a key, then just click the link below it will automatically create a key for 
you and just copy that key in  your project

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start